# Parse a php variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently getting returned in avatarName this robert.smith@hg.osgrid.org:80
I would like to only print out in html the part after the @ sign.
So my html would look like hg.osgrid.org:80  How do I break the line robert.smith@hg.osgrid.org:80 into just hg.osgrid.org:80 and discard the rest?

```
    <?php

    $query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT avatarName FROM avatari order by avatarName")
       or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo
       "<tr>
       <td>{$row['avatarName']}</td>
       </tr>\n";

    }

    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php . Then just use the part you want.

Comment: Here example: https://phpize.online/s/dp

Comment: [truncate in the SQL](https://phpize.online/s/3p)